# ui router define state on module lazy loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an application with restricted access. In order to improve the files I'm trying to move some of my states to the module it belongs. I'll try to explain the situation.

Let's say I have 2 modules:

- **app.module**: Public module, anyone can access
- **user.module**: Restricted module, only logged users can access

I also have some public states, nothing wrong with it. Code example:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/Login',
    ...
})
.state('home', {
    url: '/Home',
    ...
})
```

But I also have other states which were supposed to be available only if the user is logged. For example:

```
.state('user', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/User',
    ...,
    data: {
        requireLogin: true
    },
    resolve: {
        lazyLoad: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            // This is where I'm lazyloading the restricted module
        }
    }
})
.state('profile', {
    parent: 'user',
    url: '/Profile',
    ...,
})
```

At the moment **ALL** of my states are inside the public module (app.module), including those restricted states. The reason for this is because, if the user is already logged in and try to access his profile (first access), for example: `http://myapp.com/User/Profile` the `user.module` isn't loaded yet, so it's not a valid state.

Is there a way I can move my restricted states to that specific module and still be able to access it after the module is lazy loaded?